# Linq like search across multiple fields

Tags: .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a simple address screen where the user has a single "google" style query box which searches across all address fields i.e. address line 1, town, city, post code etc.

I'm using .net and EF with an SQL database. I've tried

```
IEnumerable<T> results = from x in dbSet
                         where (x.AddressLine1 + x.AddressLine2 + 
                                x.AddressLine3 + x.Town + x.City + 
                                x.County + x.Postcode).Contains(Query)
                         select x;
```

This does not match any results when it should. If i change it to

```
IEnumerable<T> results = from x in dbSet
                         where x.AddressLine1.Contains(Query)
                         select x;
```

It matches and returns results but obviously its not searching across all fields.  First question why is my first example not working and second is this the best way to implement this or is it going to struggle under pressure.

Comment: Are all `AddressLine1`, `AddressLine2`, `County` etc. of type `string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<T> results = from x in dbSet
                         where x.AddressLine1.Contains(Query) ||
                         x.AddressLine2.Contains(Query) ||
                         x.AddressLine3.Contains(Query) ||
                         x.Town.Contains(Query) ||
                         x.City.Contains(Query) ||
                         x.County.Contains(Query) ||
                         x.Postcode
                         select x;
```

For more complicated searches using Linq, I use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Your current approach will require a full table scan with some sub-string matching operation on each row - I can't imagine this being performant on a large table. What you really should do is use SQL fulltext. There is no native support for this in EF but you could use a stored procedure or store query.

Answer (score 1):

what happens if you use this

```
IEnumerable<T> results = from x in dbSet
 where x.AddressLine1.ToString().Contains(Query) ||
   x.AddressLine2.ToString().Contains(Query) ||
   x.AddressLine3.ToString().Contains(Query) || 
   x.Town.ToString().Contains.(Query)||  
   x.City.ToString().Contains.(Query) || 
   x.Postcode.ToString().Contains(Query)
 select x;
```